# Why is constexpr required even though member function is constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, constexpr

The following does not compile unless I put constexpr before initializer_list:

```
constexpr std::initializer_list<int> il = {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
};
std::array<int, il.size()> a;
```

But initializer_list size is constexpr:

```
constexpr size_type size() const;
```

Comment: It is not even clear if `constexpr std::initializer_list<int> li = {..};` is valid in C++11; it will be in C++1y.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
std::initializer_list<int> il = rand() ? std::initializer_list<int>{1}
                                       : std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3};

std::array<int, il.size()> a;
```

That's why.

A `constexpr` member function is a function that *can* be executed within a constant expression, it doesn't necessarily yield a result that is a compile-time constant. For example:

```
struct S
{
    int m;
    constexpr int foo() const { return m; }
};

S s{rand()};
int j = s.foo();     // only known at run-time

constexpr S cs{42};
int arr[cs.foo()];   // compile-time constant
```

Answer (score 2):

By writing `std::array<int, il.size()> a;` you are claiming that `il.size()` can be evaluated at compile time with a constant result, allowing template instantiation.

That's why both the `initializer_list::size()` method and your `il` variable need to be declared as **`constexpr`**.